# Which of the following is true for $\int_{1}^{0} x\ln x\, \text dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, divergent-series

Which of the following is true for $\int_{1}^{0} x\ln x\,\text dx$

1. it is equal to $−1/4$
2. it is divergent
3. it is equal to an irrational number
4. does not have a closed form
5. it is impossible to evaluate this integral

According to my calculations it evaluates to $\frac{2x^{2}\ln x - x^{2}}{4}$
No when I put the values for limit 0, it then comes out to be $-\infty$ for $\log x$
Then which of the options are correct?

Comment: You should have $2\,x^2\,\ln x$ instead of $2\,\ln x$

Comment: After change of variable, it is $\int_0^{-\infty}xe^x\,dx$.

Comment: @ZiqianXie: I believe it should be $\int_0^{-\infty}xe^{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: @robjohn yep, I forgot the $\frac{1}{4}$ factor.

Comment: Which is correct from option 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_1^0 x\ ln(x)\ dx = \frac{x^2}{2}ln(x)|_1^0 - \int_1^0 \frac{x^2}{2}\frac{1}{x}dx= +\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: which is correct from options 2 3 and 4

Comment: what would the correct option be if limits were from 0 to 1

Comment: That should be straightforward: $-\frac{1}{4}$